# How to update a nested reactive form based on input value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

For my scenario, I am using angular reactive forms. I have a list of dependents and each dependent has to fill up some details. I need to have a form for each dependent. The model for dependent is as follows:

```
export class Dependent {
    surname: string;
    othNames: string;
    nid: string;
    dateOfBirth: string;
    relationship: string;
    netIncExempt: number;
    exemptDiv: number;
    exemptInt: number;
    exemptOth: number;
    exemptEmol: number;
    balance: number;
}
```

I need to calculate a total for each form based on the input values.  See the html below

```
<form [formGroup]="dependentIncomeForm">
  <div formArrayName="dependentsArray">
    <ion-card [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let dependent of dependentsArray.controls; let i = index">
      <ion-card-header (click)="current = i">
        <ion-item [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dependent.valid ? 'lightskyblue' : 'lightcoral'}">
          Dependent {{i+1}}: {{dependent.controls["nid"].value}}
          <button ion-button type="button" (click)="current = i">
            <ion-icon [name]="i === current ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-forward'"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-grid class='expand-wrapper' [class.collapsed]="current != i">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Net Income and exempt Income (Rs)</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="netIncExempt" type=tel maxlength="10" allow-numbers-only></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row *ngIf="dependent.controls['netIncExempt'].errors && dependent.controls['netIncExempt'].errors.threshold">
          {{dependent.controls['netIncome'].errors.threshold.value}}
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Less: Exempt dividends (Rs)</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="exemptDiv" type="text" maxlength="10" allow-numbers-only></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Less: Exempt interest (Rs)</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="exemptInt" type="tel" maxlength="10" allow-numbers-only></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Less: Other exempt income (Rs)</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="exemptOth" type="tel" maxlength="10" allow-numbers-only></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Less: Emoluments (Rs)</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="exemptEmol" type="tel" maxlength="10" allow-numbers-only></ion-input>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-8>Balance</ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item col-4>
            <ion-input formControlName="balance" readonly></ion-input> 
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

The control balance hwich is a read-only field is calculated based on the input values of the other control values. The dependentsArray is populated based on the number of dependents. See below

```
if (this.dependentList.length > 0) {
  //this variable count represents the index of each dependent as it depends on the threshold
  let count = 0;
  this.dependentList.forEach((dep: Dependent) => {
    this.dependentsArray.push(this.fb.group({
      nid: [dep.nid],
      netIncExempt: [null, [Validators.required, validateThreshold(count)]],  //validators for dependents
      exemptDiv: [null, Validators.required],
      exemptInt: [null, Validators.required],
      exemptOth: [null, Validators.required],
      exemptEmol: [null, Validators.required],
      balance: [null]
    }));
    count++;
  });
}
```

Where I am stuck now is how to update the value of balance when the user is going to enter the other values such as net income. To be able to update a reactive form control, to my knowledge we can use patchvalue or setvalue method. What I am doing is subscribe to the form valuechanges, get each control value, create the appropriate model and then update back the form for each dependent. See below.

```
subscribeToFormChanges() {
    let dependentTemp: Dependent;
    let idx: number = 0;
    this.dependentIncomeForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      data.dependentsArray.forEach((item: Dependent) => {
        dependentTemp = this.dependentList.find((dep:Dependent) => dep.nid === item.nid);
        dependentTemp.netIncExempt = +item.netIncExempt || 0;
        dependentTemp.calculateBalancePerDependent();
        //this.updateDepForm(idx, dependentTemp.balance);
        idx++;
      });
      this.incomeDep.calculateBalForAllDependents();
    });
  }

  updateDepForm(idx: any, balance: number) {
    let formGroup = this.dependentsArray.controls[idx] as FormGroup;
    formGroup.controls["balance"].patchValue(balance);
  }
```

The line that is commented in the subscribeToFormChanges method is giving me the following error maximum call stack size exceeded. I am guessing there is some kind of circular dependency that is going on since I am listening to form changes and then updating it at the same time.

Comment: Yes in updateDepForm you trigger a value change which calls updateDepForm again

Comment: @Vega so how to set value of balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{emitEvent: false}` option on [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue), otherwise patchValue will trigger the value change intercepted by valueChanges.subscrbe...

> If emitEvent is true, this change will cause a valueChanges event on
>   the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls
>   through to updateValueAndValidity).

```
formGroup.controls["balance"].patchValue(balance,{emitEvent: false});
```

[Simple Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gh2gar)

Comment: awesome. thanks :). you think there is a better approach to this?